# How to find a bootstrap's form width?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to determine the width of a Bootstrap form, but getting illogical results.

**JS - EDITED**

```
function centerReCaptcha() {
        var sw = ($("form").width() - 232) / 2;
        console.log($("form").prop("id") + ", form-width=" + $("form").width() + ", screen-width=" + screen.width);
        $("#recaptcha-elements").parent().css("margin-left", sw);
}
```

Note: screen.width = $(document).width()

**console.log:**

> form-writers, form-width=934, screen-width=1251

**CSS** worked before but stopped working?

```
#recaptcha-elements, .g-recaptcha {
   display: inline; 
}

#recaptcha-elements{
   max-width: 100%;
}

.g-recaptcha>div>div{
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 78px;
   transform:scale(0.77); 
   -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
   transform-origin:0 0;
   -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
   text-align: center; 
   position: relative;
}
```

**screen-shot:**

[image]

The width in inches of the form is 7" and the screen is 12.5".
It seems to me the form width should be more like 700 than 934. What am I missing? Is there a way using bootstrap to determine the width of a form?

Comment: There's no way that code outputs that info in the console...You've either shared the wrong code, or the wrong console log.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? How else would it get there?

Comment: are you trying to centre an element? this is probably possible with pure css (or am i missing something about your html?)

Comment: Your code should output a console log in the following format: `form-writers, form-width=111, margin-left=111, swidth=111`. With different numbers, of course.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I posted a previous version. It is now correct. I am trying to center a ReCaptcha. I tried all kinds of CSS that just don't do the trick.

Comment: @rontornambe, im almost certain we can find a pure css solution. would you mind posting a jsfiddle or your html and css (my first instincts are to try the bootstrap 'justified' styling).

Comment: It is complicated to make a jsfiddle from this angular / bootstrap app. There is a PHP required file and ReCaptcha is built to be cryptic due to security concerns. I had a CSS solution that worked but now mysteriously stopped working. I post the CSS. Perhaps you can fashion a bootstrap CSS solution.